# Stuttering on mouseout of moved image element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, when hovering over an image, I'd like to move the image slightly and then on mouseout, return the image to the original location. I've got a version of the code that works to accomplish this task but there is a bit of a "stuttering" effect if the user was to move the mouse from the image into the area where the image was located originally.

```
          -----
          |   |
-----     |img|
|   |     |   |
|img| ==> -----
|   |     xxxxx
-----     xxxxx
```

In the diagram above, when the mouse hovers over the image, it gets nudged up 2 units. On mouseout, the image returns to the original position. My code, as below, works but when the mouse gets moved into the previously vacated area (e.g., the x's), the code thinks that it's hovering over the image again and then moves the image back up 2 units. This creates a sort of stuttering effect when hovering the mouse over the area marked by x above.

I've tried different approaches (e.g., using animate(), adding/removing a wrapper div, using setTimeout(), etc) but they all produce the same undesired effect. I considered constantly monitoring the mouse position on the page and remembering the position of the image, but that seems excessive, esp since there could be anywhere between 1 and n images.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hoverImage').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).offset({'top':$(this).offset().top-2});
        },
        function(){
            $(this).offset({'top':$(this).offset().top+2});
        }
    );
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle demo-ing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/Ut8eK/

Any tips would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Awesome. I ended up using a bit of both answers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hoverImage').wrap('<div class="hoverImageWrapper" style="display: inline-block;">');
    $('.hoverImageWrapper').hover(
        function(){
            $('.hoverImage',this).offset({'top':$(this).offset().top-10});
        },
        function(){
            $('.hoverImage',this).offset({'top':$(this).offset().top});
        }
    );
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/rf5mE/

This works great for my needs, since adding the functionality will be super easy just by adding `class="hoverImage"` to the appropriate images.

I accepted @Matyas as the answer only because his answer came through first (by about 4 seconds!).

Thanks y'all!

Comment: if you can, you should really put the div wrappers in your html and the css in a css file. For better performance even though in this case it is milliseconds, always use js when you need to. Maybe 4 seconds ahead but my answer was correct from the start

Comment: Yes, I understand. I ended up keeping the div wrappers in the js because that way it would be easier for the non-programmer user. Nonetheless, thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your images in a wrapper, and listen to the hover in the wrapper, which doesn't change its position. This way you should get a constant effect

EDIT: 
The problem is that the image moves lower on mouseout than the size of the div (original size of the image) Solution: add a 10px bottom padding to the div, in the case the image moves 10px lower, to still have a div in its background if it's hovered. (updated link)

TY Huangism for the notification

[Update example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ut8eK/6/):

HTML

```
    <br />
    <div>< img src="http://placekitten.com/120/100" class="hoverImage" /></div>
    <div>< img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" class="hoverImage" /></div>
    <div>< img src="http://placekitten.com/110/100" class="hoverImage" /></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div').hover(
    function(){
        //search for the image inside the wrapper (reffered to by this)
        $('.hoverImage', this).offset({'top':$(this).offset().top-10});
    },
    function(){
        $('.hoverImage', this).offset({'top':$(this).offset().top+10});
    }
);
});
```

CSS:

```
div{
    display: inline-block;
}
div:hover{
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't stutter for you in the fiddle? I am on a mac viewing the fiddle in latest FF and it still stutters

Comment: try version 5 (updated the link) & explained it in description

Comment: Thanks Matyas and Huangism. I was able to solve the problem with your help. The original question has been updated with the result.

Answer (score 2):

Put a wrapper on it and target the wrapper to move the image

http://jsfiddle.net/Ut8eK/4/

HTML

```
<div class="hoverImage"><img src="http://placekitten.com/120/100" /></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hoverImage').hover(
        function(){
            var $img = $(this).find('img');
            $img.offset({'top':$img.offset().top-10});
        },
        function(){
            var $img = $(this).find('img');
            $img.offset({'top':$img.offset().top+10});
        }
    );
});
```

for multiple divs you do need the inline-block css